# Find 'select' element by one of its 'option' elements?

Tags: jquery

It's easy enough to find a `select` by its `id` and get/set its selected `option`.  However, let's say I know only the value of an `option` and I first need to *find* the `select` which has that option (it's assumed there is only one) and *then* set that `option` to be selected.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I just noticed that your intention was to set the selected option by its value.

To do that, it's really simple. Just do:

```
$('#mySelect').val('somevalue');
```

If you have no other way to target that select, then you can use my previous solution, and then call `.val()`.

---

```
$('option[value="somevalue"]').closest('select');
```

This uses the [`attribute-equals-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the option where the `value` attribute equals the value you're looking for.

Then it uses the [`closest()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to grab its nearest `<select>` ancestor.

The advantage to this approach is that `'option[value="somevalue"]'` is a valid [`querySelectorAll()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll)  selector, so you'll get a performance boost in browsers that support it.

If there's more than one `<select>` with an option that has that value, you can add to the original selector to target the correct select.

```
$('#mySelect option[value="somevalue"]')
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  And an additional thanks for adding further elaboration while I was testing the code!

Comment: @Victor: Because that's the element OP was trying to get. The selector locates the `<option>`, then `closest()` grabs the `<select>` that was ultimately being targeted.

Comment: @David: I just noticed the ending of one of your sentences. There's a better way. Just use `.val()` to set the value. I'll update. Or if your only purpose for getting the `<select>` was to set the value, then you should use [@Victor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821601/find-select-element-by-one-of-its-option-elements/4821698#4821698) instead.

Comment: @patrick dw: The meat of this was really just finding the `select` based on a known `option` value.  After that, setting the value of the select is trivial, as you know.  There are other things I need to do with the `select` as well, though.  So having that object reference was key.

Comment: I thought maybe I was missing something here.

Comment: @Victor: I think my question may have been missing something.  But that's the great thing about SO... multiple good answers.  The first part of the question (find the `select`) was key, the second part (set its value) was secondary and trivial once the first part was done, just added to the original question for illustrative purposes I guess.

Comment: @David: Overall I was sloppy in my reading as I missed the ending of your question. Turned out that it still gave you what you wanted. Had I been more careful like @Victor was, I would probably have given the same answer he did. One of those rare times where my clumsiness worked toward a benefit in the end I guess. ;o)

Answer (score 4):

use this:

```
$('option[value="somevalue"]').attr('selected', true);
```

this way you dont have to bother finding the select, but this only holds if there is truly just one instance of this option, or if you want all of them to change.

Comment: Ah, I see what you were doing now.  Turns out that I need to reference the `select` for other things as well, though.  (Hiding/showing `select` elements dynamically.)  But a useful attempt to think outside the box for setting the value. +1

Comment: +1 I was assuming that OP needed the select for purposes beyond just setting the selected option. If not, then this answer would make more sense to use.